# How can I increase the maximum call stack size in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stack-overflow, callstack

This is different to other questions regarding an error message in Node that reads **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** in that I know exactly why I'm getting this error message. It's happening because I'm recursing, recursing quite a lot in fact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

From `node --help`:

```
node --max-stack-size=val
```

Update: as the comments indicate, even though the help text still lists the `--max-stack-size` option, in node v0.10.x you need to use `--stack-size` instead.

```
node --stack-size=val
```

Comment: pretty obvious now i'm looking at --help :)

Comment: For some reason, I find --stack-size work for me, not --max-stack-size.

Comment: What would be the maximum safe stack size? Would that depend on CPU cycles?

Comment: Logan, I believe this is an issue of memory.

Comment: node --stack-size=8192 is the max value on my Ubuntu Server. Anything more than that doesn't increase the max recursion of my functions. Note that the unit of --stack-size is KB, so that's about 8 MB. In Windows I can't get more than 1 MB.

Comment: having the same issue, if increase the stack size , new error come - segmentation fault

Comment: "segmentation fault" here as well

Comment: »It seems to be a common misunderstanding but --stack_size=... doesn't change the size of the stack, it tells node/V8 how big it is. If you set it to a value that's bigger than the actual size, it runs over.« - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17416#issuecomment-348545847

Answer (score 29):

In node version 5 and 6, I have verified that the option to set maximum stack size is "--stack_size" (with an underscore):

```
$  node --v8-options
[...]
--stack_size (default size of stack region v8 is allowed to use (in kBytes))
      type: int  default: 984
```

To increase the maximum stack size, just issue something like:

```
$ node --stack_size=1200
```

As noted by others, be aware that increasing this value may lead to a segmentation fault. The maximum safe value for me with version 6 is 1361, but seems higher with version 5.

Looking at the bigger picture, increasing stack size may not solve all your issues. When writing recursive functions in node, your best strategy is to write them in a [tail-recursive](http://medium.com/@dai_shi/tail-call-optimization-tco-in-node-v6-e2492c9d5b7c) [manner](http://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/), since version 6 supports proper tail calls. This will eliminate stack size overflows.

**Update**: the comment about tail calls doesn't apply to Node.js anymore. They've removed tail-call optimization from the engine in version 8. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788286/5045563) for some more info.

Comment: Problem is, there are many ways to stuff the stack - map, forEach, Promise.all....

Comment: Tail Call Opmitization is only supported by Safari - Node droped its support: https://node.green/

Comment: When i run this command it runs my node console. Please help. node --stack_size=1200

Comment: How do you find out what your max stack size value is? I'm on an AMI Linux 2 instance