# What is the default stack size in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, callstack

I know how to set the stack size thanks to:
[How can I increase the maximum call stack size in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332422/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-call-stack-size-in-node-js)

But, what is the default size?  (ie how do I get to the PHP equivalent of `phpinfo()`)

Comment: See http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html and related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748061/what-is-the-default-stack-size-in-node-js.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The simple answer is that the default stack size is 492 kBytes (32-bit) and 984 kBytes (64-bit).

As commented by soyuka try this:

```
$ node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack_size
```

or

```
$ node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack-size
```

Comment: actually, never mind, it seems to be 32/64 bit differences. Though a link would be great

Comment: Link would be good or any info on how to confirm this programmatically

Comment: `$ node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack_size`

Comment: This seems to be outdated

Comment: `node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack-size`, stack-size, not stack_size..I am on node 20