# How to extend method (monkey patch) without a temporary variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Must be phrasing my question wrong, since I cannot find existing questions on what would seem an often issue.

I have a class `Foo`.

```
var Foo = function () {
    return {
        a: function () {}
    };
};
```

I have another class `Bar` that is instantiated with an instance of `Foo`:

```
var Bar = function (foo) {
    // Does something with foo.  
};
```

I want to extend the `Foo` instance to work differently for `Bar`:

```
var Bar = function (foo) {
    foo.a = function () {
        return foo.a.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // Does something with foo.  
};
```

Doing the way I did it, will cause `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Is there a way to extend the method itself without a temporary variable?

This is the way to do it using an extra variable:

```
var Bar = function (foo) {
    var originala;

    originala = foo.a;

    foo.a = function () {
        return originala.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // Does something with foo.  
};
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a temp variable? And better yet, what are you trying to accomplish with this? It seems a bit questionable.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

You are getting maximum call stack exceeded because you are calling the same function over and over from itself (recursively).

**The reason:**

When you construct `Foo`, it gets a function assigned to its property `a`. All is well.

Next, you construct `Bar` and attempt to modify behaviour of `Foo.a` by replacing the function on the object with your own. However, you expect that within the new function's body, `Foo.a` will still contain the original function. The opposite is true - `Foo.a` now contains **your new, modified function**. That is why when you call it, it will keep calling itself until you hit a [maximum stack size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748061/what-is-the-default-stack-size-in-node-js).

This happens because variables' values are resolved at execution time and your new function is executed well after it has been assigned to `Foo.a`. The original function is lost for this object.

**The solution:**

Use [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). I will not go into detail about using prototypal inheritance as there are plenty floating around.

> Note that your approach is a valid one, and frequently the only one. You simply need to keep a reference to the original function somewhere so that you can call it at a later time.

Comment: Extending the prototype would affect all instances of `Foo`. I am monkey patching an existing instance of `foo` to behave differently in a specific domain. It is an accurate explanation of the problem. I was hoping that there is some sort of a name reference that would allow to avoid the temporary variable.

Comment: You can put the normal function to the prototype and then monkey-patch per-instance. You could also use a named function, but in order to have access to it you would need to define it outside of the class, which might look ugly in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

This becomes really easy when using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```
class Foo {
    a(){
        return /* Something */
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    a(){
        /* Do something else */
        return super.a()
    }
}
```

This wasn't possible in most browsers (if any) when this question was asked 6 years ago, but [every modern browser now supports classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#browser_compatibility).