# Large base64 image produces "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in React

Tags: reactjs

I am storing webpage content as a byte[] logo and an html body in database. When I click to load a specific category group, I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" if the logo image is too large (in this case > 200kB). But if I store the same image as a base64 tagged image inside the html body, it doesn't fail. I've searched and searched but I cant find an explanation for this behavior. I searched for other answers. I changed the way I store the image. I tested different sizes. I expect the logo to load async regardless of size. I'm newer to React; any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is the MemberBenefit object:

```
export default interface MemberBenefit {
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
    CategoryId: string;
    Logo: ImageFile;
    Detail: string;
}

export interface MemberBenefitCategory{
    id: string;
    Name: string;
    ParentId: string;
}

export interface ImageFile{
    data: number[];
    contentType: string;
    fileName: string;
}
```

The code where the logo and body are rendered is here:

```
<Accordion.Collapse eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
    <Card.Body>
        {benefit.Logo && 
            <>
                <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
            </>
        }
        <section 
            className="not-found-controller"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: benefit.Detail }}
        />
    </Card.Body>
</Accordion.Collapse>
```

Here is the whole TSX file for reference. I'm sure I am being very inefficient in many places, so I appreciate all the constructive feedback.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import {Container, Row, Col, Breadcrumb, Button, Card, Accordion} from "react-bootstrap"
import {Redirect, Link} from "react-router-dom"
import ClientApi from "../../api/ClientApi"
import {ContainsAuthExpiredError} from "../../models/ErrorDetail"
import BenefitGroupPicker from "../../views/benefits/BenefitGroupPicker"
import PageHeading from "../../views/PageHeading"

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import MemberBenefit, { MemberBenefitCategory } from "../../models/MemberBenefit"
import { faBriefcase, faCar, faCarrot, faCircle, faDollarSign, faFaceGrinWide, faHeartPulse, faHouseChimney, faPlaneUp, faSailboat, faSquare, faWrench } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"



const Index: React.FC = () => {
    const {errors, payload} = ClientApi.Account.UseAccountOverview()    
    const accountOverview = payload
    const redirectToDisabled = accountOverview?.MembershipSummary.IsDelinquent ?? false 
    
    const [categories, set_categories] = useState<MemberBenefitCategory[] >([]);    
    const [selectedParentCategoryIndex, set_selectedParentCategoryIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [loadedMemberBenefits, set_loadedMemberBenefits] = useState<MemberBenefit[] | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true
        const fetchData = async () => {
            var [_getCategories, _error] = await ClientApi.Benefits.GetMemberBenefitCategories();           

            if (mounted) {
                if (_error.length > 0) {
                    //set_benefitsLoadingErrors(allErrors)
                } else {
                    set_categories(_getCategories ?? [])
                }
            }
        }
        fetchData()

        return () => {
            mounted = false
        }
    }, [])

    const LoadParent = async (parentCategoryId:string) =>{
        var [_getMemberBenefits, _error] = await ClientApi.Benefits.GetMemberBenefits(parentCategoryId ?? 0);
        set_loadedMemberBenefits(_getMemberBenefits)
        set_selectedParentCategoryIndex(categories.findIndex(category=> category.id == parentCategoryId))
    }
    
    // maybe fold these into 1 redirection checker function?
    if (ContainsAuthExpiredError(errors)) {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
    }
    if (redirectToDisabled) {
        return <Redirect to='/memberBenefits/Disabled' />
    }
    if (accountOverview && accountOverview.MembershipSummary.IsTerminated) {
        return <Redirect to='/myMembership/PayDues' />
    }

    return (
        <div className='component_BenefitsIndex'>
            <PageHeading>
                Member <b>Benefits</b>
            </PageHeading>
            
            <Container className='pageContent'>
                <div className="d-lg-none d-xl-none ">
                    {selectedParentCategoryIndex == null  &&
                        <>
                            <div id="benefitsPicker" style={{marginTop:"15px"}}>
                                <Row style={{textAlign:"center",lineHeight:"48px"}}>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("5")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}}>
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faWrench} size='2x'/>                        
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Equipment</div>
                                        </button>                                
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("1")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                        
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white", fontSize:"30px", top:"-15px", left:"-15px"}} icon={faSailboat}/>                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E", fontSize:"25px",top:"10px", left:"10px"}}  icon={faSquare}  />                                        
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E", fontSize:"35px", top:"10px", left:"10px"}} icon={faCar} />                                                    
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E", width:"100px", height:"10px", top:"15px", left:"-7px"}}  icon={faSquare}  />
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white", fontSize:"30px", top:"10px", left:"10px"}} icon={faCar} />
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Auto/Boat</div>
                                        </button>           
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("2")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faPlaneUp} size='2x'/>                       
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Travel</div>
                                        </button>           
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                                <Row style={{textAlign:"center",lineHeight:"48px"}}>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("6")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faDollarSign} size='2x'/>                        
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Financial</div>    
                                        </button>       
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("3")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faHouseChimney} size='2x'/>                      
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Home/Farm</div>    
                                        </button>       
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("7")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faHeartPulse} size='2x'/>                        
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Health</div>   
                                        </button>       
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                                <Row  style={{textAlign:"center",lineHeight:"48px"}}>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("4")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faFaceGrinWide} size='2x'/>                      
                                            </span>
                                            <div style={{marginTop: "11px",lineHeight: "25px"}}>Attractions/<br/>Sports</div>       
                                        </button>   
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("8")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faBriefcase} size='2x'/>                     
                                            </span>
                                            <div>Career</div>
                                        </button>           
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <button onClick={() => LoadParent("9")}>
                                            <span className="fa-layers MemberBenefitsNav" style={{width:"6em"}} >
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"#FF671E"}}  icon={faCircle} size="4x" />                            
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:"white"}} icon={faCarrot} size='2x'/>                        
                                            </span>
                                            <div>FAMA</div>     
                                        </button>   
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    }
                    {selectedParentCategoryIndex != null &&
                        <>
                            <button onClick={()=>set_selectedParentCategoryIndex(null)}>back</button>
                            <div className='blockNavContent'>
                                        <h2>{categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].Name}</h2>
                                        
                                            {
                                                categories.filter(category=>{return  category.ParentId == categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].id}).map(category=>
                                                    <Accordion key={category.id+"sub"}>
                                                        <Card>
                                                            <Card.Header>
                                                                {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={category.id.toString()}>
                                                                    {category.Name} 
                                                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                            </Card.Header>
                                                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={category.id.toString()}>
                                                                <Card.Body>
                                                                    {
                                                                    loadedMemberBenefits?.filter(benefit=>benefit.CategoryId == category.id.toString()).map(benefit=>                                           
                                                                        <Accordion key={benefit.Id +"subbenefit"}>
                                                                            <Card >
                                                                                <Card.Header>
                                                                                    {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                                                    <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                                        {benefit.Name}
                                                                                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                                                </Card.Header>
                                                                                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                                    <Card.Body>
                                                                                        {benefit.Logo && 
                                                                                            <>
                                                                                                <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
                                                                                            </>
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        <section 
                                                                                            className="not-found-controller"
                                                                                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: benefit.Detail }}
                                                                                        />
                                                                                    </Card.Body>
                                                                                </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                                            </Card>
                                                                        </Accordion>
                                                                    )
                                                                    }
                                                                </Card.Body>
                                                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                        </Card>
                                                    </Accordion>
                                                )
                                            }
                                            {
                                                loadedMemberBenefits?.filter(benefit=>benefit.CategoryId == categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].id.toString()).map(benefit=>                                            
                                                    <Accordion key={benefit.Id +"sub"}>
                                                        <Card >
                                                            <Card.Header>
                                                                {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                    {benefit.Name}
                                                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                            </Card.Header>
                                                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                <Card.Body>
                                                                    
                                                                    {benefit.Logo && 
                                                                        <>
                                                                            <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
                                                                        </>
                                                                    }
                                                                    <section
                                                                        className="not-found-controller"
                                                                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: benefit.Detail }}
                                                                    />
                                                                </Card.Body>
                                                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                        </Card>
                                                    </Accordion>
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </div>
                        </>
                    }
                </div>
                <Row className="d-none d-lg-block">
                    <Col>
                        <div className="blockNavGrid">
                            <div className="blockNavsList">
                                {
                                    categories.filter(category=>{return category.ParentId == ""}).map(category=>
                                        
                                        <div key={category.id}>
                                            <Button onClick={() => LoadParent(category.id)} >
                                                {category.Name}
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    )
                                }
                            </div>
                            {selectedParentCategoryIndex == null &&
                            <>  
                                <div className='blockNavContent'>
                                    <div style={{marginBottom: "48px"}}>
                                        <img
                                            src='https://apps.floridafarmbureau.com/_cdn/img/MembershipMeansMoreHeader.svg'
                                            alt='Membership Means More'
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Membership with Florida Farm Bureau means that you are part of a
                                        growing community of member families in Florida. Members, just
                                        like you, advocate for agriculture and grow as better leaders in
                                        our state through their membership. As a thank you for your
                                        membership, you are provided with access to over 30 companies to
                                        provide benefits and discounts.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Click a section for more information. </p>
                                </div>
                            </>
                            }
                            {selectedParentCategoryIndex != null &&
                            <>  
                                <div className='blockNavContent'>
                                    <h2>{categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].Name}</h2>
                                    
                                        {
                                            categories.filter(category=>{return  category.ParentId == categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].id}).map(category=>
                                                <Accordion key={category.id+"sub"}>
                                                    <Card>
                                                        <Card.Header>
                                                            {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={category.id.toString()}>
                                                                {category.Name} 
                                                            </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                        </Card.Header>
                                                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={category.id.toString()}>
                                                            <Card.Body>
                                                                {
                                                                loadedMemberBenefits?.filter(benefit=>benefit.CategoryId == category.id.toString()).map(benefit=>                                           
                                                                    <Accordion key={benefit.Id +"subbenefit"}>
                                                                        <Card >
                                                                            <Card.Header>
                                                                                {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                                    {benefit.Name}
                                                                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                                            </Card.Header>
                                                                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                                <Card.Body>
                                                                                    {benefit.Logo && 
                                                                                        <>
                                                                                            <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
                                                                                        </>
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    <section 
                                                                                        className="not-found-controller"
                                                                                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: benefit.Detail }}
                                                                                    />
                                                                                </Card.Body>
                                                                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                                        </Card>
                                                                    </Accordion>
                                                                )
                                                                }
                                                            </Card.Body>
                                                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                    </Card>
                                                </Accordion>
                                            )
                                        }
                                        {
                                            loadedMemberBenefits?.filter(benefit=>benefit.CategoryId == categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].id.toString()).map(benefit=>                                            
                                                <Accordion key={benefit.Id +"sub"}>
                                                    <Card >
                                                        <Card.Header>
                                                            {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}
                                                            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                                {benefit.Name}
                                                            </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                        </Card.Header>
                                                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={benefit.Id.toString()}>
                                                            <Card.Body>
                                                                
                                                                {benefit.Logo && 
                                                                    <>
                                                                        <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
                                                                    </>
                                                                }
                                                                <section
                                                                    className="not-found-controller"
                                                                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: benefit.Detail }}
                                                                />
                                                            </Card.Body>
                                                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                    </Card>
                                                </Accordion>
                                            )
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </>
                            }

                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUQNw.png)

Error Text:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(anonymous function)
C:/Source/Repos/Federation.Homestead/MyFfbfPortal/my-ffbf-portal/src/pages/benefits/Index.tsx:233
  230 | 
  231 | {benefit.Logo && 
  232 |     <>
> 233 |         <img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  benefit.Logo.data)) }></img>
      | ^  234 |    </>
  235 | }
  236 | <section


Index
C:/Source/Repos/Federation.Homestead/MyFfbfPortal/my-ffbf-portal/src/pages/benefits/Index.tsx:175
  172 | 
  173 | {
  174 |     categories.filter(category=>{return  category.ParentId == categories[selectedParentCategoryIndex].id}).map(category=>
> 175 |         <Accordion key={category.id+"sub"}>
      | ^  176 |            <Card>
  177 |                 <Card.Header>
  178 |                     {/* This was Accordion.Toggle in old version */}


▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
LoadParent
C:/Source/Repos/Federation.Homestead/MyFfbfPortal/my-ffbf-portal/src/pages/benefits/Index.tsx:48
  45 | const LoadParent = async (parentCategoryId:string) =>{
  46 |  var [_getMemberBenefits, _error] = await MyFfbfClientApi.Benefits.GetMemberBenefits(parentCategoryId ?? 0);
  47 |  set_loadedMemberBenefits(_getMemberBenefits)
> 48 |  set_selectedParentCategoryIndex(categories.findIndex(category=> category.id == parentCategoryId))
     | ^  49 | }
  50 | 
  51 | // maybe fold these into 1 redirection checker function?
```

Comment: When the call stack size exceeds this is usually an indicator for something like an infinite loop, or a missing exit from a loop, a circular dependency or if you accidently access a whole tree of elements instead of a single value.

Comment: @DanielW. I definitely agree and tried to go down that rabbit hole. But I don't see where that is, or why the same sized image in the html body wouldn't produce the same error.

Comment: I see your point. Can you tell which line fails?

Comment: @DanielW. I edited the post to add the following Error screen. Thank you! https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUQNw.png

Comment: The default maximum stack size for node is relatively small https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748061/what-is-the-default-stack-size-in-node-js (on the order of your image size) so there's a plausible explanation that it (or a deconstructed representation) is somehow being stored on the stack itself.  If it is due to this fixed size you can try increasing that size as a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332422/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-call-stack-size-in-node-js

Comment: @possum You are right with that but, there should be a way in JavaScript to encode a buffer in a single call instead of one call per byte. But maybe I am wrong, curious to learn from this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this: `String.fromCharCode.apply` it gets invoked for **each** byte/number in `benefit.Logo.data` **inline** and at a certain size the call stack exceeds.

> The apply() method calls the specified function with a given `this`
> value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

> But beware: by using apply this way, you run the risk of exceeding the
> JavaScript engine's argument length limit. The consequences of
> applying a function with too many arguments (that is, more than tens
> of thousands of arguments) varies across engines. (The JavaScriptCore
> engine has hard-coded argument limit of 65536.)

So internally it looks like this:

```
// `null` will be replaced with the global object
btoa(window.String.fromCharCode(benefit.Logo.data[0]) + window.String.fromCharCode(benefit.Logo.data[1]) + ...)
```

Maybe you can store the image as raw binary, like in `Image()` or `ArrayBuffer()` or similiar and call `toString("base64")` on that?

Pseudo code:

```
export interface ImageFile{
    data: ArrayBuffer;
    contentType: string;
    fileName: string;
}

<img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + benefit.Logo.data.toString("base64") }>
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

Comment: So I changed my API to pass the data as a string which allowed me to change the Image tag to the below. The smalls images work just as before. But still fails on the massive one with the same exact error. 

<img style={{width:"100%"}} src={"data: "+benefit.Logo.contentType+"; base64," + benefit.Logo.dataToString }></img>

Comment: @CurtisC What does `dataToString` look like?

Comment: public string DataToString
  {
    get { return Convert.ToBase64String(data); }
  }

Comment: @CurtisC I'm out of ideas then, sorry! Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: Me too. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: This actually did work. I got in a hurry and forgot had a typo in my typescript interface object. All is well with the world now. Thank you!