# How to set maximum stack size in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pandoc

I got error while converting docx to epub.

I have increased stack size but task is vain.

The error:

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Array.filter (native)
at writeAll (D:\xxx\WorkingFolder\xxxx\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\html-generator.js:73:15)
at Object.text (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\ACS_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\html-generator.js:12:13)
at DocumentConversion.elementConverters.text (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\x_x\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:229:18)
at elementToHtml (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\xx_xx\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:71:13)
at eval (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\xxxx\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:64:20)
at iterate (D:\xxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:134:13)
at Object.async.eachSeries (D:\xxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:150:9)
at convertElements (D:\xxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:63:15)
at convertRun (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:122:9)
at elementToHtml (D:\xxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:71:13)
at eval (D:\xxxx\WorkingFolder\xxx_Live\public\node_modules\mammoth\lib\document-to-html.js:64:20)
```

Solution:  **Actually this is not node.js error but mammoth(see the above error log). While converting doc to epub, style is not converting.  That is there was no proper valid document.  I check and remove that pages. Now it is working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

Use
`node --stack-size=val` 
to change max stack size.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332422/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-call-stack-size-in-node-js), but I don't know how to mark duplicates. Do I not have enough permissions? Can anyone give me a tip in the comments? Thanks..

Comment: Click "close" in the question and select the reason "duplicate of..." and add your linked question.

Comment: i am using windows.  What is the value of "val"?  It is not taking in application.

Comment: 'Val' can be whatever number you like, but I expect your problem might have more to do with the code you are running than anything that could be fixed by manually increasing the stack size.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes.  But i donot know to the max size to handle large file(client can use any size) and i want to configure the size at global in my computer.  This is very basic as i am new.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This answer is not my solution.  I am workaround the solution.  At last i got it. The problem is that document is not proper ie  2 pages from 855 pages.   Actually this is not node.js issue but in mammoth. Note:  Need to create proper valid document.