# Get count of odd numbers in a given integer recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

Good day, I am trying to get the number of odd numbers in a given integer, say 15 should return 7, 3 should return 1, etc... Now i was able to do that simply in a for loop, but I want to achieve it recursively now. This is my code:

```
var count = 0;
function oddCount(n){ 
    if(n !== 0 && !isNaN()) {
        return count;
        if(n%2 === 0) {
            count ++;  
            return oddCount(n-1); 
        } else {
            return oddCount(n-1); 
        }
    }
} // oddCount();

console.log(oddCount(14));
```

The console always returns an undefined value.
Thank you for any support in advance. :)

Comment: *"3 should return 1"* It should? I take it 3 doesn't *contain* 3 then?

Comment: *"Now i was able to do that simply in a for loop, but I want to achieve it recursively now."* There's an even simpler way: `Math.floor(n / 2)`.

Comment: Two typo-style errors jump out: 1. `!isNaN()` will always be `false`, because you haven't passed anything into `isNaN`, so it will check `undefined`, which coerces to `NaN` and thus `isNaN` will return `true` -- and then the `!` inverts it to `false`. 2. `if (n%2 === 0)` checks for an **even** number, not an odd one. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: You said you wnated odd count but `if(n%2 === 0)` gives you even count

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well you just helped me by pointing out the `!isNaN()` function, i removed it, returned count, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @BeedZSh.: I thought that might help! But there was an aspect of this specific to recursion (I take it you're doing this for practice/to learn), so I posted an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there's a typo in that you're not passing anything into `isNaN`.

But looking at the recursion aspect: With a recursive function, you almost **never** want it to operate on something it closes over (`count` in your case). You want it to be pure.

So instead, keep everything local within the function (or passed in as a parameter). You can think of recursive functions as being a bit like state machines: Each call just needs to work out the answer for its single input, but then aggregate that with the result of the recursion (aggregate = add in this case). See comments (obviously, this is verbose for the purposes of explanation):

```js
function oddCount(n){ 
    // Zero => zero, NaN => NaN
    if (n === 0 || isNaN(n)) {
       return n;
    }
    // n % 2 is 0 for evens, 1 for odds.
    // Count the value for the one *below* the one passed in (since when
    // checking 3 we only want to check 0, 1, and 2, e.g., not the 3 as
    // well).
    // Then simply add in the result of the recursive call:
    --n;
    return n % 2 + oddCount(n);
} // oddCount();

console.log(oddCount(0));  // 0
console.log(oddCount(1));  // 0
console.log(oddCount(2));  // 1 (1)
console.log(oddCount(3));  // 1 (1)
console.log(oddCount(4));  // 2 (1 and 3)
console.log(oddCount(14)); // 7 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, and 13)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted. 1 thing tho is that I didnt really understand what happened in `n%2 + oddCount(n)`.

Comment: And Im getting **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error when i input large numbers

Comment: @BeedZSh.: That's the nature of recursion, you only get to go so many levels before you run out of stack (unless tail-call optimization can be done -- which it could here, but most JavaScript engines still don't support it [and some may never do so]).

Comment: @BeedZSh. About `n % 2 + oddCount(n)`: As I said in the comments above it, `n % 2` will be 0 for an even number or 1 for an odd number. Then we take that value (0 or 1) and add the result of calling `oddCount` recursively for the next value, and that lets us add up the total.

Comment: You're a beast really. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to track the count externally, instead, try to increment the value that's returned from your function. Also, as others have pointed out, the increment needs to happen when n % 2 is not 0, e.g. :

```
function oddCount(n){ 
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  return n % 2 === 0 ? oddCount(n - 1) : oddCount(n - 1) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your odd comparison wrong, also your `isNaN` condition will always evaluate `true`

```js
var count = 0;

function oddCount(n) {
  if (n == 0 || isNaN(n)) {
    return count;
  } else {
    if (n % 2 === 0) { // If n%2 is 0 then n is even.
      return oddCount(n - 1);
    }
    count++;
    return oddCount(n - 1);
  }
}

console.log("Number of ODD numbers: " + oddCount(15));
```

Answer (score 0):

> And Im getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error when i input large numbers

TJ's answer is great, per usual. I'll include this answer because it addresses the stack-overflow issue. Below, we look at a simplified implementation of `oddCount`.

```js
const oddCount = n =>
  n === 0
    ? 0
    : (n % 2) + oddCount (n - 1)
    
console.log (oddCount (0))  // 0
console.log (oddCount (1))  // 1
console.log (oddCount (2))  // 1
console.log (oddCount (3))  // 2
console.log (oddCount (4))  // 2
console.log (oddCount (5))  // 3
console.log (oddCount (15)) // 8

// i can't do it, captain!
console.log (oddCount (100000)) // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

To fix this, we have to move the recursive call into [*tail position*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call); meaning all other evaluation of the function is complete and making the recursive call is the *last* thing your function does...

We can do this in a variety of ways, but one versatile technique involves simply adding a state parameter (or more, if needed) to your function. Here, we add `acc` which represents an *accumulated* sum of the odd numbers and set the default value to `0`.

```js
const oddCount = (n, acc = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : oddCount (n - 1, acc + (n % 2))
    
console.log (oddCount (0))  // 0
console.log (oddCount (1))  // 1
console.log (oddCount (2))  // 1
console.log (oddCount (3))  // 2
console.log (oddCount (4))  // 2
console.log (oddCount (5))  // 3
console.log (oddCount (15)) // 8

// but still broken???
console.log (oddCount (100000)) // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Most importantly, notice the position of `oddCount` now – all of the arguments to `oddCount` can be completely evaluated and only thing left to do is recur `oddCount` – we have achieved a tail-recursive form!

```
// ...
: oddCount (n - 1, acc + (n % 2))
```

In a language that supports tail-call elimination, that's as far as you'd need to go to avoid your stack error. As of today however, JavaScript has no such optimisation. ES6 standard included support for tail-call elimination, but somewhere along the lines [it became politics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207534/633183) and the optimisation seems to be stuck in feature limbo for the time being.

No problem though. JavaScript already supports infinite looping with `while`, so we can [invent our own mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183) to write stack-safe recursive functions even in a language that doesn't have tail call elimination. Cool!

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ tag : recur, values : values })
   
const loop = f =>
{
  let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.tag === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const oddCount = n =>
  loop ((m = n, acc = 0) =>
    m === 0
      ? acc
      : recur (m - 1, acc + (m % 2)))
    
// now it works for huge numbers
console.log (oddCount (10000000)) // 5000000
```