# Tail recursion optimized javascript code performance worse than non optimization, it's counterintuitive，Is it because the compiler doesn't optimize?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, v8, tail-recursion

```
function factorialNormal(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return n
  }
  return n + factorialNormal(n - 1)
}
```

```
function factorialWithTail(n, acc) {
  if (n === 1) return acc;
  return factorialWithTail(n-1, n + acc)
}
```

recursion function is fast than tail-recursion and the tail **use more memory**, causing the maximum call stack

[image]

Detailed answer here: [ES6 Tail Recursion Optimisation Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788139/es6-tail-recursion-optimisation-stack-overflow)

Comment: AFAIK, v8 does not have tail recursion optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no TCO on V8 currently.

[Here is the tracking ticket for this feature](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4698).