# Maximum call stack size exceeded in chrome and Out of stack space in IE (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a recursive method like this:

```
PrintRecursive = function (arr, level) {
    for (var key in arr) {
        var term = arr[key];
        htmlArr.push("<li><input type=\"radio\" name=\"tempName\" id=\"" + term.Id + "\" data-taxonomy-url=\"" + term.Url + "\" /><label for=\"" + term.Id + "\">" + term.Title + "</label>");
        if (term.ChildTerms !== undefined && term.ChildTerms != null) {
            htmlArr.push("<ul>");
            PrintRecursive(term.ChildTerms, ++level);
            level--;
            htmlArr.push("</ul>");
            htmlArr.push("</li>");
        }
        else {
            htmlArr.push("</li>");
        }
    }
}
```

it generates `Out of stack space` in IE and `Maximum call stack size exceeded` in Chrome when it tries to execute htmlArr.push. arr is an array of arrays but total number of items in arr are 385 items.
Do I get this error becuase I used recursive method which is being called too many times? or because htmlArr contains too much data (html)?

Answer (score 1):

This means your recursive function hits browser's specific call stack limit.

To fix it and for more informations Take a look at following post:
[Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)