# Capybara specs fails after opal js update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rspec3, opalrb

Previously I used to load opal.js, opal-parser.js, opal-jquery.js(version 0.3x). Now I added gem opal and opal-rails(version 0.6.2) instead of js files.

Previously my whole test suit(capybara + rspec) used to passed but after update capybara specs start failing. Sometime it behave wired(i.e passed in firefox but fail in chrome).

One of the example error is

`unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

It is said that there is compatibility issue with opal and rspec.

I will be grateful if someone help me fixing this issue.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error Did you accidentally import the same JS file twice?

Comment: Sorry, but there are no duplicate import

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its a known bug in the chrome webdriver:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=683

Comment: Is there any quick fix for this?, Currently this problem only occurs when I require opal-rails gem. @elia-schito

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry. You can try to push on the issue to see if they fix it.