# No recursive function, still getting a Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm experimenting with Node, Express and Mongoose. Here's part of my model -- `book-model.js` which exports its schema and methods for use in a controller. I'm implementing the fat model, skinny controller approach:

```
// ...

BookSchema.statics.create = function(title, author, category, callback) {
    var Book = mongoose.model('Book');
    Book.create({
        title: title,
        author: author,
        category: category
    }, callback);
};

// ...

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

And here's part of the controller -- `books-controller.js`:

```
// ...

var Book = require('./book-model');

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var title = req.body.title,
        author = req.body.author,
        category = req.body.category;
    Book.create(title, author, category, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/add-book');
        }
        res.redirect('/books');
    });
});

// ...
```

Now, when I attempt to create a new book document, I get the annoying **Maximum call stack size exceeded** message. I had a look at a similar question here on SO: [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error) and the answer is that *"Somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. This is almost always because of a recursive function with a base case that isn't being met."*

I can't see a recursive function in the `books-controller.js` file that has a base case that isn't being met or what is it that I'm missing?

Please advise.

Comment: I could be off, but it looks like whenever you make a book for the first time, it redirects to this same function again after the first time is done.

Comment: Does that error refer to a line number? What does the call stack look like? You should be able to see the what's being called over and over from that.

Comment: What's the handler for `'/books'`? If you redirect there, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: I'm receiving nothing from the console apart from a `500` status code. `/books' is handled by a GET method and that's where I get to see a list of all the books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your recursion:

```
BookSchema.statics.create = function(title, author, category, callback) {
    var Book = mongoose.model('Book');
    Book.create({
        title: title,
        author: author,
        category: category
    }, callback);
};
```

Basically, you're declaring a `Book.create` method that calls `Book.create`. Since javascript doesn't have operator overloading, it doesn't realize that your redefinition conflicts with the older `Book.create` that takes only two arguments.

Rename the function to something else like `make` to break the recursion:

```
BookSchema.statics.make = function...
```

Comment: Or for hilarity `Book.crrrreate` to remind you that this version has four arguments :)

Comment: This worked. Strangely, I'm left even more confused. Because you see, I've also got an Album model that has an `AlbumSchema.statics.create` method and also uses `Album.create`, and I've had no recursion problems with it. Since I wired the Album model first and things worked that way, I figured I won't have any issues with `BookSchema.statics.create` and `Book.create`. Anyway, thanks!