# android memory (maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: android, memory, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm getting an memory error but the app doesn't crash, after closing the error I can still use it.

I've a app with a main view, that changes the content every time that the user opens another page:

```
<Window>
    <ScrollView id='menu'/>
    <View id='content'/>
</Window>
```

And update the content like this:

```
var data,
update = function(page) {

    data.cleanup();
    data = null;
    data = Alloy.createController('content/'page).getView();
    $.content.add(data);
};
```

Exemple of the cleanup function:

```
$.somepage.cleanup = function() {

    data.button.removeEventListener('click',data.click);
    for(var i in data.slides) data.slides[i].cleanup(); //widgets
    data = args = null;
};
```

This is what I get in the error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [6643,90546] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,90546] - In ti:/titanium.js:0,0
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,90546] - Message: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,90546] - Source: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, Titanium, Ti, glob
```

The only thing that shows a lot of times in the Appcelerator console is on Trace level and it's this:

```
[TRACE] :  TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
```

I've added the available memory function every time that I remove a controller and add a new one:

```
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [162,162] Titanium 5.1.1 (2015/11/24 11:07 e46100b)
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 3m 18s 95ms
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [596,758] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[WARN] :   feature: [BMW]init phonw window
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [187,187] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[WARN] :   linker: libti.paint.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = pt.winsig.aktionserver.mobile.dev.MobileDevActivity@23fb2b19
[INFO] :   OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
[ERROR] :  E/        : appName=pt.winsig.aktionserver.mobile.dev, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
[ERROR] :  E/        : 0
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: (in-house)open = 0xb5355bb9
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: (in-house)close = 0xb5355c51
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: (in-house)alloc = 0xb5355ea1
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: (in-house)ref = 0xb5355ed1
[INFO] :   art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2367(218KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(215KB) LOS objects, 3%% free, 22MB/23MB, paused 6.460ms total 18.772ms
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: (in-house)unref = 0xb5355ef9
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: gralloc tlcMemOpen recount = 0
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: gralloc call tlcMemOpen
[ERROR] :  E/[MALI][Gralloc-ERROR]: void gralloc_private_TEEopen():946 tlcMemOpen fail, ret = -65536
[INFO] :   I/[MALI][Gralloc]: gralloc tlcMemOpen recount = 1
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Analytics Service Started
[WARN] :   APSAnalyticsService: Network unavailable, can't send analytics
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Stopping Analytics Service
[ERROR] :  function DisplayCaps() { [native code] }
[WARN] :   feature: [BMW]init phonw window
[WARN] :   art: Suspending all threads took: 6.111ms
[INFO] :   art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7928(381KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(1484KB) LOS objects, 17%% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 8.403ms total 87.589ms
[WARN] :   TiUIScrollView: (main) [3673,3673] Scroll direction could not be determined based on the provided view properties. Default VERTICAL scroll direction being used. Use the 'scrollType' property to explicitly set the scrolling direction.
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Analytics Service Started
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Stopping Analytics Service
[WARN] :   APSAnalyticsService: Network unavailable, can't send analytics
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 1298912
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 1292560
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 509244
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 476780
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 2706008
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 2639976
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [9580,89599] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,89600] - In ti:/titanium.js:0,0
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,89600] - Message: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,89600] - Source: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, Titanium, Ti, glob
[WARN] :   feature: [BMW]init phonw window
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/titanium.js:0: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
[ERROR] :  libEGL: cache file failed CRC check
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 376096
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 352352
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 1823912
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 1554560
[ERROR] :  SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on documents_lines(obrano)
[INFO] :   WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 47.0.2526.100 (code 252610000)
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 3478-3480)
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "47.0.2526.100", actual native library version number "47.0.2526.100"
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "47.0.2526.100", actual native library version number "47.0.2526.100"
[INFO] :   chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(122)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
[INFO] :   cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
[ERROR] :  SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
[ERROR] :  E/        : appName=pt.winsig.aktionserver.mobile.dev, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
[ERROR] :  E/        : 0
[INFO] :   art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 31679(1819KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 13%% free, 25MB/29MB, paused 1.739ms total 105.475ms
[WARN] :   cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
[ERROR] :  WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 1018608
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 710728
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 1553480
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 1542872
[INFO] :   art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22703(1557KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12%% free, 28MB/32MB, paused 1.792ms total 114.905ms
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 1439904
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 1399504
[INFO] :   art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 92433(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(756KB) LOS objects, 12%% free, 27MB/31MB, paused 1.681ms total 109.455ms
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 597104
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 558848
[INFO] :   MEMORY BEFORE: 3212440
[INFO] :   controller check close
[INFO] :   controller check destroy
[INFO] :   controller run destroy
[INFO] :   controller check off
[INFO] :   controller run off
[INFO] :   MEMORY AFTER: 3168808
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [3687,145587] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,145587] - In ti:/titanium.js:0,0
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,145587] - Message: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,145587] - Source: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, Titanium, Ti, glob
[WARN] :   feature: [BMW]init phonw window
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/titanium.js:0: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
[INFO] :   MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
```

Comment: Why you don't use tabs? Have you any restriction on this architetture?

Comment: It's a large number of pages and modules, and sometimes the content depends on an id.

I think that by doing this way, it clears all the previous page data right?

Comment: main question updated: I've added the available memory function every time that I remove a controller and add a new one & console logs

Comment: it looks like a loop happening with no end

Comment: Between the logs of  MEMORY AFTER and MEMORY BEFORE it's me when I click to open another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum call stack size exceeded is not about available memory.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

I suspect it's something wrong with the widget's `cleanup()` function or something wrong when you put it in a `for` loop.

Comment: I had a bug in the android cleanup function that wasn't appending in iOS, after some days around the code, I had to re-create that function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add these lines of code at your cleanup function:

```
// let Alloy clean up listeners to global collections for data-binding
// always call it since it'll just be empty if there are none
$.destroy();

// remove all event listeners on the controller
$.off();

// remove any listeners you added to global proxies
Ti.Gesture.removeEventListener('orientationchange', onOrientationChange);

// and custom global dispatchers (all at once, via context)
myDispatcher.off(null, null, $);

// in turn, let controllers of required views clean up
$.requiredView.cleanup();

// and close windows of controllers you created, triggering them to clean up as well
someWindow.getView().close();

// this is not needed if someController cleans up well and we have the only reference
// someController = null;
```

I found and use these rules in this article, take a look:

http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/18/cleaning-up-alloy-controllers/

Comment: My cleanup function is the same, but I only use one Window.

Comment: Every time that I require an Alloy controller or Alloy widget this is what I do:

`var clients = Alloy.createController('clients').getView();`

Than clean up like this:

`clients.cleanup();`

This is an exemple of a controller/widget:

`$.widget.name = args.name`

`$.widget.addEventListener('click',somefunc);`

`$.widget.cleanup = function() {`
    `$.destroy();`
    `$.off();`
    `$.widget.removeEventListener('click',somefunc);`
    `somefunc = args = null;`
`};`

Comment: main question updated: I've added the available memory function every time that I remove a controller and add a new one & console logs