# how to catch a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, callstack

```
  try {
     requestAnimationFrame(function re(){
       re();
     })}
  catch (e){
       console.log(e);
     }
```

I tried above code in console, it doesn't work as expected. It seems to me that although

```
 requestAnimationFrame(function re(){
       re();
     })}
```

will eventually trigger an error, what throws to the `try` is insteadly the animation's id. How do I catch such a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Comment: Those errors usually come from infinity loops right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `requestAnimationFrame` ?

Comment: Also the thing about catching a maximum stack size exceeded error is I'm not sure how it would work. The only thing that the browser could do to allow the error to be caught is empty the stack then have the next function run be the catch function but at that point (and I don't think browsers can even get it that far) you would have no indication on where your code broke so anything you tried to run would be severely buggy at best.

Comment: Thanks you this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Okay I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the thing about catching a maximum stack size exceeded error is I'm not sure how it would work. The only thing that the browser could do to allow the error to be caught is empty the stack then have the next function run be the catch function but at that point (and I don't think browsers can even get it that far) you would have no indication on where your code broke so anything you tried to run would be severely buggy at best.

Another problem (which is probably why no browsers have this) is because most functions you would run after the error would simply try to restart normal web function in some way. Since you don't know what broke you can't stop it from happening again so you would end up crashing it again and again. Which would make both the users and the browsers mad at your web page.

So I guess the best that can be done is make sure your code doesn't have infinity loops and is able to run smoothly

a good description of stack size and how it works can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error?rq=1)

Comment: **This is incorrect.** You are describing handling an out of memory error, which is different. [**It is entirely possible to catch these exceptions, they do not behave any differently than typical exceptions,** see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733190/7952582).

Answer (score 10):

Maximum call stack size exceeded errors **can** be caught just like any other errors:

```js
try {
  function recur() { recur(); };
  recur();
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("caught " + ex);
}
```

What to do in this situation (call stack size exceeded) is not defined in the ECMAScript specification, but in practice, all browsers do throw catchable exceptions. However, lacking a spec different browsers have chosen to throw different types of exceptions: I've seen `Error`, `RangeError` and `InternalError`.

The problem in your code is unrelated to that. The problem is that you're trying to catch exceptions that happen when you call `requestAnimationFrame()`. But your `re()` function doesn't run at that point, it runs during the next frame, as you requested. Inside of `re()`, you can wrap the recursive call to `re()` and catch the stack overflow exception there instead:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function re(){
  try {
    re();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("caught " + ex);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the same function within the function `re()` inside your `requestAnimationFrame()` function. A correct way would be as follows:

```
function re(){
    //code here
    requestAnimationFrame(re); //loop back to start
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is not the answer to my question, but it is the answer to a question I was about to ask.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this is not an infinity loop where his code is an infinity loop. Using requestAnimationFrame in that way will cause the function to run until something causes it to stop but it's not technically an infinity loop because requestAnimationFrame is only called right before the browser is ready to redraw the Dom so you're not running a function continually like was in his question you're running a function periodically

Comment: To clarify, I was only answering the second part of your question, I don't personally know how you could successfully catch a maximum call stack size error. Here's some information [on JavaScript Stack Sizes](http://bahmutov.calepin.co/javascript-stack-size.html), with some information on calculating their size.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be certainly done**. More than that – if you'll stick to a meaningful pattern, you can determine how many times your function had run before the call stack overflowed (I wouldn't dare to try it on a function that is recursively *invoked*, rather than *returned*, as in the original question, because in this case the call stack can get really funky):

```
function doRecursionOrDieTryin(n = 0) {
    try {
    return doRecursionOrDieTryin(n + 1);
  } catch(err) {
    return `There was an exception: "${err}" when tryin' to make iteration no. ${n}`;
  }
}

doRecursionOrDieTryin()
```

**Warning**: This function starts an infinite loop, so it could crash you browser if you will try to run this in a distant future, when the common JS engines will be fully tail-call-optimized. For 10/2018, it gots to iteration no. 10454 in Chrome 69. In Firefox 62 the limit of stack overfow is changing (from 10077 to 20989, then 22160), probably due to some kind of smart runtime optimization. Haven't test it yet in Edge.