# Recursion triggers the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded error"

Tags: javascript, recursion, max

I get the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded error" when calling this recursive JavaScript.

This is my code:

```js
var num = 12
,maxlength = 50;
var lengths = [5,6,7,8,4,4,5,6,3,3,2,2];

function knap(maxlength,num){
 if(maxlength==0) return 1;
 if(maxlength<0||(maxlength>0&&num<1)){
  return 0;
 }

 if(knap(maxlength-lengths[num],num-1)){
  console.log(lengths[num]+" ")
  return 1;
 }

 return knap(maxlength,num-1);
}

if(knap(maxlength,num)){
 console.log('Yes');
}else{
 console.log('No');
}
```

How can I figure out this?

Comment: There's not much to figure out, you have a function that calls itself indefinitely, you pass in `50` so none of the if statements are true, it goes to the end, and calls the function again with `50` and the same thing happens over again.

Comment: Did you get the terminating condition right? maxlength is same always

Comment: Aha, after the first iteration maxlength eq NaN. :) So terminating condition always false.

Comment: Just curious, could you describe (informally) what your function is supposed to do?

Comment: And Peter, IMHO you spend much less time to solve this issue if you insert something like `console.log(maxlength,num)` at first string of your function body. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first time call you function value of num is exceed the length of lengths array. So expression `maxlength-lengths[num]` in `if(knap(maxlength-lengths[num],num-1))` is NaN. After that all your break recursion conditions alway is false. 
So, probably, you need to make first call as `knap(maxlength,num-1)`.

Comment: Thank you, you'vebeen most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit and it is most of the time because of recursion.

See [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error])