# Template not working on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have try to compile the app from my android device on visual studio 2015 this template https://github.com/ezazwar1/flipboard

but the app not working.

I installed it but I have no ionic Had Success

Davide from Italy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of including links to your code, please include the code directly in your question that is having an issue. Also please be more specific but what your are not having success with/ how is the app not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you launch the app with ripple on visual studio works and the console will not be mistakes , but if I launch debugging on my device gives me the following errors . [errors in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAQr2.jpg)

Comment: The error means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. Similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error).