# solve the max Maximum call stack size exceeded cause by extjs gridpanel when checkboxselected some row and click the column header to sort

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

- when i keep the checkbox which is leftest have no any dischecked, i click the table hearder to sort correctly, but when exist any checkbox status checked like picture2, the error become js stack error and could't find call stack path in chrome dev.
  i have try below two path to solve.
- try 1: try to find the event before the gridPanel sort, `deselectAll()` the checkboxselect status. but i can't find any gridPanel event before sort event occur.
- try 2: like the extnet api, i copy the rowselect event override  code, also failed.

Comment: Did you try to take a look into this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: somewhere in your code leading to infinite loop.

Comment: thanks first. but there's use extnet 2.2.
and the code like http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Selection_Models/Checkbox_Selection/ 
but in my environment, i keep 1 or more checkbox selected, and i click the header to sort, but error occur.