# Why is the following image.onload throwing: "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded"?

Tags: javascript

The following code update some data, refetches it, and then waits for an image field to load:

```
api.updateBuildings(payload).then(result => {
  this.fetchBuildings(() => {
    const image = new Image()
    image.src = result.data.web
    this.setIsLoading(false)
    image.onload = () => {
      console.log('LOADED:', image.onload())
    }
  })
})
```

However, `image.onload` throws `Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded`.

Why is this?

**EDIT:**

`result.data` looks like this:

`{
  app: "http://ac-0uhksb6K.clouddn.com/370b989e0ceec6329fb6.jpg?  imageView/2/w/4096/h/2048/q/100/format/png"
  categoryType : "livingroom"
  web: "http://ac-0uhksb6K.clouddn.com/370b989e0ceec6329fb6.jpg?imageView/2/w/4096/h/2048/q/100/format/png"
}`

Comment: Why are you recursively invoking `image.onload()`? that too without any break  condition

Comment: @Satpal - that's the answer, not a comment...

Comment: @Satpal, Oh, I was just logging it to check what the function returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is simple. You are recursively invoking `image.onload()` without any break condition. As a result method is continuously invoked until you hit the call stack limit.

Problem statement is

```
console.log('LOADED:', image.onload()); //<==========
```

A good read [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Answer (score 2):

Because you call `image.onload()` in your `console.log` function, thus creating a recursion. You might want to change your log to something like this:

```
 image.onload = () => {
      console.log('LOADED:', image.src);
 }
```