# zone.js: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular

I try angular2 [basic demo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart), when i start index.html with `google-chrome path/to/index.html`, it raise:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (zone.js:1319)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:911)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
    at HTMLBodyElement.desc.get (zone.js:913)
```

How to disable it?

my env is:

```
linux mint xfce 18
google-chrome 55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Comment: Sounds like an endless loop.. check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6095695/5357459).. did you make any changes to the demo?

Comment: @adriancarriger no, I just `npm i` and `npm start`

Comment: I just tried it on my machine (macOS Sierra v10.12.1) and it's working fine.. so I'm not sure what's going on :/

Comment: @adriancarriger my os is linux mint, I update my question

Comment: Sorry I can't help with Linux.. good luck!

Comment: try to paste the `npm outdated` output here pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i disable chrome extensions, not error is raised
i re-enable chrome extension one by one, I found "Screenshot Capture(Better than Google's)", will cause this question, I remove it.
now everything work well

Comment: Thanks! For me, the "Color Contrast Analyzer" extension caused the range error from zone.js with an angular 2 app. Going through the extensions one by one and enable/disabling them helped me find the problem extension. I wonder why this is, and if there is something to fix it.