# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a maximum call stack error and can't figure out why. It's saying jquery and only jquery i'm using is for my ajax....

jquery.min.js:6 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

here is my code

```
function processPhase3(){
    client_info.primary_email = _("emailAddress").value;
    client_info.phone = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.primary_text = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.primary_voice = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.hphone = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.agree = _("agree");

    // if check true
    // then check if email or number in the text field
    if(client_info.agree.checked == false){
        _("alertThree").style.display = "block";    
    }else{
        _("alertThree").style.display = "none"; 
    }
    if(client_info.phone.length > 3 || client_info.primary_email.length > 3){
        _("alertFour").style.display = "none";  
        _("phase3").style.display = "none";
        _("phase4").style.display = "block";
        _("progressBar").classList.remove("progress-bar-success");
        _("progressBar").className += ' progress-bar-success';
        _("progressBar").style.width = '100%';
        _("status").innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: client_info,
            url: "my_prefs_save.php"
        });
    }else{
        _("alertFour").style.display = "block"; 
    }
```

}

Comment: where is client_info instantiated ? Can you show us a how a console.log(client_info) looks like ?

Comment: For your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: Can you look at the stack trace provided in the error to get a sense of where the issue originates?

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys,

looks like adding some return statements fixed the problem ;)

```
function processPhase3(){
    client_info.primary_email = _("emailAddress").value;
    client_info.phone = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.primary_text = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.primary_voice = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.hphone = _("cphone").value;
    client_info.agree = _("agree");

    // if agree check is true - proceed if countOne = 1, false turn on error
    // if pn or email exist - proceed countTwo = 1, else turn on error
    // then check if email or number in the text field
    if(client_info.agree.checked == true){
        _("alertThree").style.display = "none"; 
    }else{
        _("alertThree").style.display = "block";
        return; 
    }
    if(client_info.phone.length > 3 || client_info.primary_email.length > 3){
        _("alertFour").style.display = "none";  
        _("phase3").style.display = "none";
        _("phase4").style.display = "block";
        _("progressBar").classList.remove("progress-bar-success");
        _("progressBar").className += ' progress-bar-success';
        _("progressBar").style.width = '100%';
        _("status").innerHTML = "Congratulations!";
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: client_info,
            url: "my_prefs_save.php"
        });
    }else{
        _("alertFour").style.display = "block";
        return;
    }
```