# Maximum call stack size exceeded in jsrender.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsrender

I am facing the error while creating 900 columns in the table by using jsrender. I have used the below code.

```
        var i = 0, htmlStr =  "<tr style = 'height: {{:height}}px' idx = '{{:rowidx}}'>" , colgrp = document.createElement("colgroup"), templates ={obj:""};
        while (i < 900) {
            colWth = 20;
            colHdr = "A" + 1;
            col = document.createElement("col");
            col.style["width"] = colWth + "px";
            htmlStr += "<td class='{{:" + colHdr + "_className}}' rowspan=' {{:" + colHdr + "_rspan}}' colspan=' {{:" + colHdr + "_cspan}}'>{{:" + colHdr + "_value}}</td>";
            colgrp.append(col);
            i++;
        }
        templates["obj"] = htmlStr + "</tr>";
        $.templates(templates);
```

While running the sample getting the error.

> JsViewsError {name: "JsRender Error", message: "Syntax error↵Compiled template code:↵↵// obj↵var v…↵return ret;↵: "Maximum call stack size exceeded""}

The error occurring in  **> jsrender-1.0.0-beta.js <** . Which is working fine in exact *jsrender-1.0.0-beta.js* version. Could you please suggest any solution to work in all the versions.

**JSFiddle link**: https://jsfiddle.net/z8fqs1yb/2/

Comment: make sure that your recursive function has a base case which is able to be met

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Please check the JSFiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Chrome. In other browsers it renders without error. In Chrome it errors if you put `while (i<900)`, but if you put `while (i<400)` (or less) it works without error.

Your way of creating the template has 900 * 4 = 3600 `{{: ...}}` tags in a single template. Chrome throws an error while compiling that template - because of some kind of limit they have on JavaScript expressions of the form

```
var ret="..." +((v=...)!=null?v:"") + "..." +((v=...)!=null?v:"") + "..." +((v=...)!=null?v:"")...
```

(where you have >7200 such terms added together to produce a single string variable).

I'd suggest you instead use a template along the lines of

```
<tr style = 'height: {{:height}}px' idx = '{{:rowidx}}'>
  {{for cols}}
    <td class='{{:_className}}' rowspan=' {{:_rspan}}' colspan=' {{:_cspan}}'>{{:_value}}</td>
  {{/for}}
</tr>
```

Then you can render the template with data which has a cols array of 900 items for the columns:

```
var data = {
  height: 220,
  rowidx: "a",
  ...
  cols: [
    {_value: "AVal", _className: "AClass",  ...},
    {_value: "BVal", _className: "BClass", ...}
    ...
  ]
};
```

See same reply here: [jsrender/issues/325](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/325#issuecomment-309583622)

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned was a **bug** in the version `0.9.86`. It was a `jsviews` bug causing the issue which was discussed and closed [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/304)

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/304

Use the version above it(`1.0.0-beta`) and the error should not be appearing. You can check all the versions from the link below:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jsrender/1.0.0-beta

Comment: I have used **jsrender.1.0.0-rc.70.js** version, issue still exists. The issue is not reproduced only the **version 1.0.0-beta** . Here i have used higher than v1.0.0-beta but issue exists. https://jsfiddle.net/z8fqs1yb/4/

Comment: You can't use the `1.0.0-beta` ?

Comment: I need to use latest version, which is **1.0.0-rc70.js**

Comment: If the issue fixed in **1.0.0-beta.js** means it should work in higher versions. i'm a correct?

Comment: not necessarily, they might have done some changes to bring out the issue again.

Comment: See if something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error) helps you

Comment: The latest version is actually 0.9.86 available at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jsrender/0.9.86

Comment: Note that the bug mentioned above https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/304 is actually quite unrelated to the issue here...