# Async.eachSeries gives me an rangeerror: maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: node.js, async.js

I want to iterate over 4435 products in an collection. For every product I want to download the image and upload it to an Amazon S3 bucket. For the last part I have written an function what is working fine.

But after a 750 products node.js crashes without giving me an error. With the `> output.log &` function I get an

> 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

I using `async.eachSeries` to iterate over the products and the product images. This is the complete function which will loop over all the products. As you can see I comment out the 'counter', but that was not enough. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
module.exports.putImagesToAmazon = function(req, res){
    console.log("putImagesToAmazon");
    var resultArray = [];
    //var counter =0;
    Product.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, products){
        console.log("aantal producten", products.length);
        async.eachSeries(products, function(product, callback){
            if(product.images.length > 0){
                async.eachSeries(product.images, function(image, cb){
                    if(image.src){
                        if(image.src.indexOf("http://") !== -1 || image.src.indexOf("https://") !== -1){
                            upload.uploadStream(image.src, 'product-image', function(err, data){
                                if(err) {
                                    console.log("ERROR1", err);
                                    resultArray.push(err);
                                    cb();
                                }else{                              
                                    image.src = data;
                                    product.save(function(err, result){
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.log("saving product error", err);
                                        }else{
                                            console.log("product updated", product.name);
                                        }
                                     })
                                    cb();
                                }
                            })
                        }else{
                            cb();
                        }
                    }
                }, function(){
                    //counter++;
                    console.log("next");
                    callback();
                })
            }
        }, function(){
            console.log("callback", counter);
            var fields = ['statusCode', 'statusMessage', 'error', "url"];
            var csv = json2csv({data: resultArray, fields: fields});

            fs.writeFile('errors.csv', csv, function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("saved");
            })
        })
    })
    res.send("Ok");
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: Maybe, you forget a cb() in else of if ( image.src)

Answer (score 2):

To help you,
Just put a :

```
//counter++;
console.log("next");
// to avoid Maximum call stack size exceeded error
setImmediate(()=>{
 callback();
});
```

Comment: This answer does solve the problem, but could you elaborate on why this solves the problem/ what the original problem is caused by