# Override find method in LoopBack

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

i'd need to override the remote method find in llopback.
i tried this in my model:

```
'usestrict';

module.exports = function(Movimenti) {
  Movimenti.once('attached', function(obj) {
    Movimenti.find = function(filter, empty, cb) {
      cb(null, this.find({
        "where": {
          "mov_utente_fk": 2
        }
      }));
    }
  });
};
```

but i get this error:

> 500 Maximum call stack size exceeded

could you help me??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Comment: the error is the same, but my problem is that I should override a method in LoopBack, and I do not know if I'm doing the right way!!

Comment: a jQuery function for loopback ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope` in model definition of your model JSON file:

```
"scope": {
        "where": {
            "mov_utente_fk" : 2
        }
    }
```

From the [Loopback Documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.modelsettings.scope.html):

`Scope enables you to set a scope that will apply to every query made by the model's repository`