# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have received

> **ERROR:** "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I suspect that this block of code in my componentWillUpdate method is the cause, since I've only been receiving the errors right after I added the code. Is there anything that I've done wrong here?

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

...

if (nextProps.show) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.actions.length; i++) {
    if (this.props.data.actions[i].assignedTo !== this.state.userId && this.state.showActions === true) {
      this.setState({ showActions: false })
    }
    if (this.props.data.actions[i].assignedTo === this.state.userId && this.state.showActions === false) {
      this.setState({ showActions: true })
    }
  }
 }

...

}
```

nextProps.show is set to true when a button is clicked, then it checks whether the person assigned an action is the same as the user that is logged in, then it will set the state showActions to true. This state is used to display/hide rows if the conditions in the code are met

Comment: It means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. As described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting `state`, this would be calling `componentWillUpdate` again, thus this recursive call is the reason for stack exceeding.

Unlike `componentWillMount()`, we should not call `this.setState()` in `componentWillUpdate()`. The reason we do not call `this.setState()` is that the method triggers another `componentWillUpdate()`. If we trigger a state change in `componentWillUpdate()` we will end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state` is not yet mutated in `componentWillUpdate`.

As a reuslt, use `nextState` instead of `this.state` to verify the value was well after using `this.setState`:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

...

if (nextProps.show) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.actions.length; i++) {
    if (this.props.data.actions[i].assignedTo !== this.state.userId && nextState.showActions === true) {
      this.setState({ showActions: false })
    }
    if (this.props.data.actions[i].assignedTo === this.state.userId && nextState.showActions === false) {
      this.setState({ showActions: true })
    }
  }
 }

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [React componentWillUpdate docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate):

> Note that you cannot call this.setState() here; nor should you do
>   anything else (e.g. dispatch a Redux action) that would trigger an
>   update to a React component before componentWillUpdate() returns. If
>   you need to update state in response to props changes, use
>   componentWillReceiveProps() instead.

You should move your code to `componentWillReceiveProps` method.