# Angular app throwing exception "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" while using id in route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my Script:

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-route.min.js" />
var app = angular.module("myBlogApp", ["ngRoute"])
   .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       $routeProvider
       .when("/home", {
           templateUrl: "Views/HomeTest.html",
           controller: "homeController"
       })
       .when("/post/:Id", {
           templateUrl: "Views/singlepost.html",
           controller: "singlePostController"
       })

       .otherwise({
           templateUrl: "Views/HomeTest.html",
           controller: "homeController"
       })
       $locationProvider.html5Mode({
           enabled: true,
           requireBase: false
       });
   })
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("Data/post.json")
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.posts = response.data;

                        });

    })

    .controller("singlePostController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "single post";
    })
```

This is my Home view:

```
<h1>home</h1>

<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <a href="post/{{post.postId}}">{{post.title}}</a>
    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
</article>
```

Now, based on the post id in the route, specific data is displayed on the singlepost.html view and it is rendered at `<ng-view>` directive as follows:

This is my index.html page:

```
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

but when I click on the hyperlink to see a particular post(say post with id 2), the url shows *http://localhost:55657/post/2* but the application is throwing "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" exception and becomes unresposive.

Comment: The RangeError object indicates an error when a value is not in the set or range of allowed values. 
check your solution in this [thread][1]. 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error