# Bootstrap validator plugin error with input type=number

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrapvalidator

When I load page Bootstrap validator plugin is showing error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace ().

When I remove name attribute of the input, there is no error. Same code is working on another page i.e. by using same validator & jquery files. I have extracted only this piece of code but its still showing error.

Here is the code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="http://localhost/my_sites/suzuki/web-reports/plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- validator -->
        <link href="http://localhost/my_sites/suzuki/web-reports/plugins/validator/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="f" action="f.php" method="post" >
          <input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="0" />
          <input type="submit" id="a" name="a" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Save" />
        </form>

        <!-- jQuery --> 
        <!--jQuery v2.2.4--> 
        <script src="http://localhost/my_sites/suzuki/web-reports/plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <!--Bootstrap v3.3.6-->
        <script src="http://localhost/my_sites/suzuki/web-reports/plugins/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- validator --> 
        <!--@version     v0.5.3, built on 2014-11-05 9:14:18 PM--> 
        <script src="http://localhost/my_sites/suzuki/web-reports/plugins/validator/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#f').bootstrapValidator();
            });        
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at String.replace ()
>       at fa (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.fa.matches (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.n.filter (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at z (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.is (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at b._getMessageContainer (bootstrapValidator.min.js:11)
>       at b._getMessageContainer (bootstrapValidator.min.js:11)
>       at b._getMessageContainer (bootstrapValidator.min.js:11)
>       at b._getMessageContainer (bootstrapValidator.min.js:11)

Comment: It would be nice if you could reproduce the bug on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Or just debug it on [browser devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is NOT structured by Bootstrap classes (the element containing field and associated label does NOT have form-group class), you will see the error.
Go through this jsfiddle. you will get a solution

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/x7pooh99/
```

Comment: Very thx resolved, cant imagine this was the error cost my 5 hours :(. Just need 1 more clarification, originally the form is placed within table. is it safe to add form-group class to td?