# How to use date time picker in sweet alert?

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert

This is my code i am working on

```
   swal({
                title: "Confirm details?",
                text:'<input id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" autofocus>',
                type: "warning",
                customClass: 'swal-custom-width',
                html:true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false,
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true
            },
```

I want to set date time picker in the input inside sweet alert.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

When i clicked on the sweet alert, the input field unable to click or do any action on it. The date also didnt show up. Anyone can tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Console error when click on input select date

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at HTMLDivElement.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at Object.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at Function.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at c.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
at HTMLDocument.f (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
```

Comment: And you are trying to add html in `text:` field, I am not sure sweet alert 1 supports HTML tags on `text`

Comment: sweet alert 1 put the content into text and allow html by html:true

Comment: Oh, Okay then. :+1:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **onOpen** listerner to trigger `datetimepicker`

```
onOpen: function() {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
         format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
         defaultDate: new Date()
  });
},
```

In your case something like this:

```
 swal({
    title: "Confirm details?",
    html:'<input id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" autofocus>',
    type: "warning",
    onOpen: function() {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
            defaultDate: new Date()
        });
    }
}
```

Reference: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: I tried, but not working. I am using sweetalert not sweetalert2.

Comment: Yeah, i am using this one.

Comment: This version does not support , these kinda listeners , either you have to migrate to swal2 or use this custom script add support for OnOpen for swal1 http://jsfiddle.net/w8guq08p/5/

Comment: I tried, but not working also, the input field also unclickable as well. For the onOpen function, i simply added alert but nothing display also when click on my button.

Comment: Rather than wasting time on make swal work, I suggest you migrate to https://sweetalert2.github.io/, it has lots of functionality and more customizable. I hope  It is not a huge migration, just core CSS, and js file replacing.

Comment: It works, but the input field unable to edit. Do you know what's the problem? Although it can choose date, just wonder why the input field unable to edit.

Comment: Check console for JS errors. That patch is not fully tested one.

Comment: I updated my question with the error when click on the input field select date.

Comment: Seems like something goes recursive. I am afraid, its hard to fix and waste of time. when already solution is available with sweetalert 2/

Comment: I don't think it related to the onOpen function. For the normal input i only can show but unable to edit also.

Comment: checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: Thanks. But the main problem for me is the text field unable to edit, no idea why.

Comment: I too have no idea, you better to ask a separate question, others may help you.

Comment: Is there any way other than use onOpen() in swal 1? Something missing in the script like jsfiddle.net/w8guq08p/5, showloaderConfirm.

Comment: Glad to know :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thamaraiselvam.
Here is my way, Using SweetAlert2 and JqueryUI DatePicker:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'pick a date:',
  type: 'question',
  html: '<input id="datepicker" readonly class="swal2-input">',
  customClass: 'swal2-overflow',
  onOpen:function(){
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
 });
  }
}).then(function(result) {
 if(result.value){
  alert( $('#datepicker').val() );
 }
});
```

```css
.swal2-overflow {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.2.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js" integrity="sha256-Ry2q7Rf2s2TWPC2ddAg7eLmm7Am6S52743VTZRx9ENw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"/>
```