# Maximum call stack size exceeded error when converting jquery element object to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a jquery element as object:

```
var created = $('#object');
```

and I want to parse it to JSON with this method:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(created);
```

but its throwing

> Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Is there any way that I can get this element as JSON?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Looks like the element you are trying to stringify is huge, what exactly you need to do with this element?

Comment: A jQuery object has too many properties to be converted to json. What exactly are you trying to get

Comment: You might be facing a loop. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: @Eddie I have an object that has this element inside it. And i need to convert to JSON to save it

Comment: @Senal i need to return to JSON and save it to DB

Comment: @ErwinMoller I already did but theres nothing about this particular, how to deal with element objects

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz There is an object that has many properties, and one of them should be the elment object.

Comment: @ErtanHasani Yes, but you have a jQuery object which has alot of properties. You   might want to consider only including the the properties that you may need in the future.

Comment: @Eddie I will do it like that because it seems that there is no other option

Answer (score 0):

the dom elements have a lot of child properties that references other parent properties and because of this you have a loop to serialize it. If you analyse your $('#object') on console you can view what i'm talking about.
Using `JSON.stringify(created, function (k, v) { return k ? "" + v : v; });`
you avoid this.

Comment: this is not working, since its returning `[object Object]` as string

Comment: This is suposed to work on root element only, if you "enter" on objects you have the same problem. If you need the html of the element this can be simples like element.innerHtml, but if you have to serialize as JSON you have to chose upfront the properties you want. Serialize a full Jquery object it's impossible because the circular references.