# RangeError not being raised - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When the following code is run:

```
(function recur() {
    recur()
})()
```

the following error is raised —

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

— with the stack filled with references to the function (`recur`).

So why does the following code:

```
(function recur() {
    try {
        recur()
     } catch (error) {
        recur()
     }
})()
```

even though the error is caught in the `try` block, not **return the error in the `catch` block**? Or at least **complain about the function overflowing the call stack**?

When the code is run, it does pause all other non-asynchronous code from executing, but still... no errors?! **What's going on here?**

---

**EDIT:**

This behavior is especially weird with code like this:

```
(function notRecur() {
    try {
        Symbol() + 2
    } catch (error) {
        Symbol() + 2
    }
})()
```

that returns a `TypeError` when executed.

Just another question to experiment with, thanks for reading through and replying.

Comment: For every `RangeError` that could get thrown, you create a *new* `catch` handler. If you're handling *every* `RangeError`, where do you expect an *unhandled* `RangeError` to come from?

Comment: I'm still a bit lost. What I figured would happen is that the `RangeError` would get thrown in the `catch` handler preventing the script from calling the `recur` function again.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error will help

Comment: The `RangeError` is *thrown* in the `try` block and *caught* in the `catch` block. Once you've *caught* the `RangeError`, it's like it never happened. Then, in your `catch` block, you call `recur` again. This time around, you create a whole *new* `catch` block to handle the next `RangeError` that occurs, etc, etc. You have tonnes of these `catch` handlers due to the recursion - not many of them will actually see a `RangeError` occur, but when they do, they squash it and continue on with the recursion.

Comment: RE your edit - that's *entirely* different. For that, just run `Symbol() + 2` completely standalone and you'll get a `TypeError`. There's no recursion involved here - so the error occurs in the `try` and is then handled in the `catch`. In your `catch`, you generate the same error but there's no `catch` for this as there's *no recursive creation of `catch` handlers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got endless recursion, the call stack gets filled up until it reaches a memory limit and crashes, in that case the error bubbles up and unwinds the stack:

```
 call > call > call > call > call > | memory limit
    <----------------------------- error
```

Now you directly catch that and retry:

```
 call > call > call > call > call  | memory limit
                           < error |
                           > call  |
                           < error |
                           > call  |
                           < error |
                           > call  |
                           ...
```

Although it looks very strange it doesnt fill up memory. However it blocks the browsers thread, so the browser might kill the whole thread after some time.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an infinite loop of catched `RangeError` exceptions.

It will execute the `recur` call within the `try` block until the maximum call stack size is exceeded. Thereafter the `catch` block will be executed the first time and call `recur` again - leading to a `RangeError` exception - that's caught in the `catch` block - and so on.

To help visualize this, you can print the stack trace in your `catch` block *before* starting the recursion:

```
(function recur() {
    try {
        recur()
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        recur()
     }
})()
```