# Google Tag Manager dataLayer.push errors with large, deeply nested objects

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm attempting to use Google Tag Manager `dataLayer.push` to push a large, deeply nested object into the dataLayer, but getting the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)

/\[object (Boolean|Number|String|Function|Array|Date|RegExp)\]/.exec(Object.prototype.toString.call(Object(a))
```

I am sure the dataLayer is set up correctly as I'm able to push smaller objects into it. Additionally, If I pass the object I am trying to push to the data layer to the line above, it does not throw an error.

Can GTM/dataLayer just not handle large objects?

Answer (score -1):

have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error) answered question? It says that the error occurs when calling to much functions within another function or that there might be a problem with a recursive function.