# What's a maximum call stack size exceeded error and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a list where the user can add his or her favorites. But then I got a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

What is that and how do I fix it?

I'd appreciate the help, thank youuu

Here are the codes that I used:

```
    <body onload="onload();">
        <!--for everything in the navigation part including the add favorite bar-->
        <div class="topnav">
            <!--links to the other pages-->
            <a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="games.html">Games</a>
            <a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
            <a href="series.html">TV Series</a> 
            <a href="books.html">Books</a>

            <!--for the add favorite button-->
            <div class="addFave">
                <!--the text bar-->
                <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="added"  placeholder= "Add Favorites"/>
                <!--the enter button-->
                <input type="button" value="Enter" id = "addIt" OnClick="adding()" />
                <!--for the script of the add favorite bar to add its functions-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var faves = [];

                    var y = document.getElementById("added");
                        function adding() {
                            faves.push(y.value);
                            document.getElementById("faveLists").innerHTML = faves;
                        }
                    var input = document.getElementById("added");
                        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                            document.getElementById("addIt").click();
                        }
                    }); 
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>




        <!--for the additional texts-->
        <div class="list">
            <!--where the user input in the add favorite bar will appear-->
            <p id = "faveLists"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when does the error happen? I ask because nothing I see here should cause that error. what is in your `onload()` function?

Comment: I copied it from somewhere, it was used to add the "add favorite button"

Comment: Ok. well I have tried the code you posted here, and it works. I am lead to believe the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Oh I see. But when I run it on google it gives me this games.html:93 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)
    at onload (games.html:93)

Comment: `onload (games.html:93)` means it is your `onload` function that's causing this

Comment: ohh, okay I'll look into.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I don't know Javascript well

Comment: if you put the code in your question i can look at it

Comment: Really? that'd be helpful, wait

Comment: where's your `onload()` function ?

Comment: oh wait, it's in the body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Maximum call stack size exceeded.` appears when you enter something like an infinite loop of function!

Check a better example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095695/5560399)

In your `<body>` you are typing: `onload="onload();"` and that's the reason of your problem because `onload` is calling itself, over and over. Try to remove it from your code, and the error will be disappeared.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Is it not needed? I just used it since i copied it from someone and thanks

Comment: It's okay to copy others, most of us do it, but you need to understand what you are copying... In your case, there is no need for it at all! :)

Comment: oh I see, it's gone now. Thank you :)

Comment: and may i ask one more thing?

Comment: You're welcome. If you find it helpful, select it as the correct answer, so that it gets pinned!

Comment: If it's related to the answer, yes sure! But, if it isn't, I suggest you to create another question as it would be more helpful for newcomers who might search for it!

Comment: An infinite loop will not cause a stack overflow. while (true) {} is not placing anything on the stack.

Answer (score 10):

So you have come to StackOverflow to ask what a stack overflow is?

Distilling it down to just the onload it is still happening. Onload is calling itself in an unending recursive loop causing a stack overflow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">

    </body>
</html>
```

But adding an onload function fixes it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function onload() {
          console.log('Onload called');
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">

    </body>
</html>
```