# return-object in Treeview causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Vuetify

Tags: object, vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

I have a `Treeview` and I am interested in accessing the entire object once a node is selected. In 
[treeview](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview) there is a property named `return-object` that ideally does that.

> `return-object`: When true will make `v-model`, `active.sync` and
>   `open.sync` return the complete object instead of just the key.

But when I try that I get this error: **Maximum call stack size exceeded.**

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
 <v-treeview
        v-model="selected"
        return-object
        item-text="node.text"
        :items="all"
        activatable 
        open-on-click
        selectable>
</v-treeview>

all: [
{
    "node": {
        "text": "child1",
        "instances": ["test1"],
        "props":[{
            "text":"some",
            "instance": ["text"]
        }]
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "node": {
                "text": "child2",
                "instances": [ "test"],
                "props":[{
                      "text":"some",
                        "instance": ["text"]
                    }]
            }
        }
    ]
  }]
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you tell us what's in `:items="all"` ?

Comment: I updated the question with my data. The actual data is bigger than this. It just shows the structure

Comment: Is the actual data deeper than this structure ? And how far ? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: Yes but I tried with hard-coded data that was not big at all. same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the format of provided data for `items` prop is not compatible (refer [`VTreeviewNodeProps`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTreeview/VTreeviewNode.ts) for a list of supported node properties) with [`Treeview` component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview#treeview). That's the reason why the specified error occurs once the node is getting selected.

Given the provided data format, the following function could be utilized to transform data to supported format:

```
getNodes(items){
   return items.map(item => ({
    id: item.node.text,
    name: item.node.text,
    children: item.children ? this.getNodes(item.children) : []
  }))
}
```

**Example**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-treeview v-model="selected" selectable open-on-click :items="items"></v-treeview>
    <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

const all = [...]


export default {

  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
  }),
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.getNodes(all)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getNodes(items){
       return items.map(item => ({
        id: item.node.text,
        name: item.node.text,
        children: item.children ? this.getNodes(item.children) : []
      }))
    } 
  }
};
</script>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/MxXagm)

Comment: @DjSh, it is just the fact that Treeview expects the following format for data: `[{id: <id>, name: <name>,...,children: [...]}, ...]`

Comment: I think you forgot to add `return-object` to your `Treeview`