# AJAX MySQL Change Value Of Inputs

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to change the value of two textboxes based on the result of a MySQL query.
I have the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="userfname" name="frsname"
    value="" /> 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="userlname" name="lstname" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>

<script>
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: form,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#userfname").html(data[0]);
                $("#userlname").html(data[1]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

    require 'config.php';

$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id=?");
if(!$stmt2) {
    die($link->error);
}
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['id']);
if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
    die($stmt2->error);
}
$stmt2->bind_result($fname, $lname);
$stmt2->fetch();
$stmt2->close();

$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $fname;
$arr[1] = $lname;

echo json_encode($arr);

$link->close();
?>
```

How can I solve this error? I would like to return the values from the select query and update the input values. Thank you.

Comment: Use `.val()` to change the value of an input, not `.html()`.

Comment: `data: form,` doesn't make sense.

Comment: The PHP script doesn't use any POST parameters, you don't need to use `data:`

Comment: already answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error - in short, you probably have the same JS called multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data: form` tries to convert the `<for>` element to url-encoded data, which doesn't work. Since the PHP script doesn't use any POST parameters, you don't need that line.

You should also prevent the default form submission with `event.preventDefault()`.

To fill in the `<input>` fields, you need to use `.val()`, not `.html()`.

```
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#userfname").val(data[0]);
                $("#userlname").val(data[1]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: why is this the accepted answer since a POST is not required?

Comment: It will work just as well as GET. GET can also run into caching issues, although that's probably not an issue in this application.

Answer (score 2):

Also change this `<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />`

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting any values so a $.getJSON should be used instead. Put your php in a file getUserDetails.php Also use val() jQuery method to update inputs values.

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $.getJSON("getUserDetails.php").done(function(json) {
        $("#userfname").val(json[0]);
        $("#userlname").val(json[1]);
    });
});
```