# Dynamically add/remove validators based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, ionic4, angular-forms

**Scenario:**

Initially I have one text box(`Name1`), one date picker(`DOB1`) and a check box (`Compare`). Both `Name1` and `DOB1` are required. When check box is clicked, two more form controls are dynamically added named as `Name2` and `DOB2` and either any one of `Name1` or `DOB2` are required.

so the valid form is having any of

1. `Name1` `DOB1` `Name2` or //If `Name2` is valid then need to remove required validator from `DOB2`
2. `Name1` `DOB1` `DOB2` or //If `DOB2` is valid then need to remove required validator from `Name2`
3. `Name1` `DOB1` `Name2` `DOB2`

In all the above cases, the form is valid show enable the submit button.

**Issue:**

I had tried using setValidators but still couldn't figure out what i'm missing. When I click the checkbox, the form is valid only when all four controls are valid. I just need any three of them valid.

**Code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ion-card class="person1">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-list lines="full" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Name / Number <ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="NameNumber"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Date of birth<ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-datetime required placeholder="Select Date" formControlName="DateOfBirth"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card class="person2" *ngIf="isComparisonChecked">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-list lines="full" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Name / Number <ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="NameNumber2"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Date of birth<ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-datetime required placeholder="Select Date" formControlName="DateOfBirth2"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-item class="compare-section" lines="none">
    <ion-label>Compare</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="danger" formControlName="IsCompare"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-button color="danger" *ngIf="LicensedStatus" [disabled]="!this.profileForm.valid" expand="block"
      type="submit" class="ion-no-margin">Submit</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Ts:**

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
NameNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$')]),
DateOfBirth: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
IsCompare: new FormControl(false)
});
...
this.profileForm.get('IsCompare').valueChanges.subscribe(checked => {
if (checked) {
    this.profileForm.addControl('NameNumber2', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$')]));
    this.profileForm.addControl('DateOfBirth2', new FormControl('', Validators.required));

    this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valid) {
        this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').clearValidators();
      }
      else {
        this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').setValidators([Validators.required]);
      }
    this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').updateValueAndValidity();
    });

    this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valid) {
        this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').clearValidators();
      }
      else {
        this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$')]);
      }
    this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
  else {
    this.profileForm.removeControl('NameNumber2');
    this.profileForm.removeControl('DateOfBirth2');
  }
});
```

What am I missing here?

**Update #1:**

I have updated the above code. If I use `updateValueAndValidity` i'm getting this error in the console

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `updateValueAndValidity()` emits another `valueChanges` event. So your subscriptions trigger each other infinitely.

```
this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  // omitted
  this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').updateValueAndValidity(); // Triggers valueChanges for 'DateOfBirth2' 
});

this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  // omitted
  this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').updateValueAndValidity(); // Triggers valueChanges for 'NameNumber2' 
});
```

One way to avoid this is already described in previous posts: Using `distinctUntilChanged`.

A cleaner way is built into the method itself though: `updateValueAndValidity()` takes an object to configure its behaviour. `updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false})` will prevent the `valueChanges` event to be emitted and thus stop the event loop.

```
this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  // omitted
  this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false}); // Does NOT trigger valueChanges
});

this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  // omitted
  this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false}); // Does NOT trigger valueChanges
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').setValidators([Validators.required]);
this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Tried that, but getting some error. Please see the updated question

Comment: I think basically i'm hitting this  issue  if i use updateValueAndValidators, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Answer (score 0):

Using **distinctUntilChanged** from **rxjs/operators** will solve the Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Change the line from

```
this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
```

to

```
this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => {
```

So, the overall code will change as like below.

```
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => {
     if (this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').valid) {
        this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').clearValidators();
     }
     else {
       this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').setValidators([Validators.required]);
     }
     this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').updateValueAndValidity();
  });

this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(() => {
     if (this.profileForm.get('DateOfBirth2').valid) {
        this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').clearValidators();
     }
     else {
        this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$')]);
     }
     this.profileForm.get('NameNumber2').updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

I ran the above changed code, The form is valid and submit button is enabled for all the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. This works but i prefer the other one. But I learned new thing about `distinctUntilChanged` :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a customValidator over all the form? You emit differents errors and check the error over form. A function auxiliar indicate you waht fields has errors
Some like:

```
  form=new FormGroup({
    name1:new FormControl(),
    date1:new FormControl(),
    compare:new FormControl(),
    name2:new FormControl(),
    date2:new FormControl(),
  },this.customValidator())

  hasError(error:string)
  {
    return this.form.errors?this.form.errors.error.find(x=>x==error):null
  }
  customValidator()
  {
    return (form:FormGroup)=>{
      const errors=[];
      if (!form.value.compare)
      {
        if (!form.value.name1)
            errors.push('name1')
        if (!form.value.date1)
            errors.push('date1')
      }
      else
      {
          ....
      }
      return errors.length?{error:errors}:null
    }
  }
```

And your form like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name1"/>
  <span *ngIf="hasError('name1')">*</span>

  <input formControlName="date1"/>
  <span *ngIf="hasError('date1')">*</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="compare"/>
  <br/>
  <input *ngIf="form.get('compare').value" formControlName="name2"/>
  <span *ngIf="hasError('name2')">*</span>
  <input *ngIf="form.get('compare').value" formControlName="date2"/>
    <span *ngIf="hasError('date2')">*</span>
</form>
```

Another idea is similar, has a customValidator that return always null, but use setErrors to give manually an error to your fields

```
  customValidator()
  {
    return (form:FormGroup)=>{
      const errors=[];
      if (!form.value.compare)
      {
        if (!form.value.name1)
            errors.push('name1')
        if (!form.value.date1)
            errors.push('date1')
      }
      else
      {
         ....other logic...
      }
      form.get('name1').setErrors(errors.find(x=>x=='name1')?{error:"required"}:null)
      form.get('date1').setErrors(errors.find(x=>x=='date1')?{error:"required"}:null)
      form.get('name2').setErrors(errors.find(x=>x=='name2')?{error:"required"}:null)
      form.get('date2').setErrors(errors.find(x=>x=='date2')?{error:"required"}:null)
      return null
    }
  }
```