# How to hide href in the browser when click on a anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button which is an anchor with a href as an attribute, I want to try the following:

When the user clicks on the anchor button, JQuery catch this event and it prevents the event and then JQuery clicks on the href.

The purpose of this is to avoid shows in the URL the href when the users click on the anchor button, e.g: wwww.mysite.com/#control

I have the following to accomplish this but the following error appears me when I click on the anchor button: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```html
<a href="#control" id="someID"> Go to control panel</a>
<div id="control"><input type="number" id="prices" placeholder="Price" required></div>
```

```
$('#control').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'www.someUrl/endPoint',
      async: false
    })
    .done(function(){
        console.log('GET Method done')
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('GET Method fail')
    });
});
```

```
$('#someID').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#control').trigger('click');
});
```

Any help is welcome here.

Comment: what is point of having href , why done you have click function ?

Comment: your code working properly.

Comment: FYI, from [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings): "**As of jQuery 1.8**, the use of `async: false` with jqXHR (`$.Deferred`) is deprecated".

Comment: and for your error see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error]

Comment: thanks but the link does not help me with my issue