# ngx-pagination "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngx-pagination

I'm using the [ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination) package in an Ionic with Angular application.

As you can see in the attached Stackblitz, I created a custom component which receives two input params `currentStep` and `totalItems`. We start in the HomeComponent page. If we click the "ClickMe" button, we go to the InstructionsPage, which makes use of the custom pagination template. The thing is that, if I press the "Go back" button, I return to HomeComponent but, if I press the "ClickMe" button again, an error is thrown.

[image]

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5s2qwc

Answer (score 1):

change **goback** method in **instructions.component.ts** to this it will not show error

```
  public goBack(){
    this.nav.pop();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the problem. But I'm still wondering what the root cause is. I mean, under the hood, what is the difference between `pop()` and `push()` in this case?

Comment: You're welcome.Kindly take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error