# Get Error while insert PDF by RichTextEditor in MVC 5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rich-text-editor, richedit, richtextediting

I'm using [RichTextEditor](http://richtexteditor.com/) for content and I'm trying to insert PDF, its display dialog contains this message when click insert PDF icon

> Unable to parse /richtexteditor/dialogs/insertdocument.xml?160322a , Maximum call stack size exceeded

Pic for issue:
[image: Pic for issue]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error