# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when dispatching action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have changed my es6 classes to functions, and now get the above error when I try and dispatch an action in my child component, passed down as a prop. Any ideas?

Container:

```
import {bookmarkVideo} from '../actions/videos';
export default function VideoPlayerScreen(props) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  ...

  const bookmarkVideo = id => {
    dispatch(bookmarkVideo(id));
    navigate('Video Player');
  };

  return (
    <>
          <VideoPlayerHeader
            {...videoProps}
            onClick={bookmarkVideo}
          />
            ...
            </View>
```

Child:

```
export default function VideoPlayerHeader(props) {
    let {title, bookMarked, icon, id, onClick} = props;

    return (
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => onClick(id)}> // dispatch action
```

Videos.js:

```
export const bookmarkVideo = video => ({
    type: "BOOKMARK_VIDEO",
    video
});
```

Comment: Check the updated answer please

Comment: How can I import the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch function receive an object as a first parameter, and that object needs to have a type and a payload according to redux conventions.

I think you get that error because you have a recurrence issue. You are calling the same function again and again.

```js
export default function VideoPlayerScreen(props) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  ...

  const bookmarkVideo = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'BOOKMARK_VIDEO',
      payload: id
    });
    navigate('Video Player');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <VideoPlayerHeader
        {...videoProps}
        onClick={bookmarkVideo}
      />
        ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Please check the documentation for more information [Hooks · React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

Also this answer may be useful. [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error?rq=1)

Comment: I have passed the function as you describe and still get the error

Comment: How can I import my action from a different file? I've edited the question

Comment: Actions are just Javascript plain objects, you can import and export using ES6 modules. Check this web for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export