# Maximum call stack size exceeded to download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using a Direct Web Remoting (DWR) JavaScript library file and am getting an error in chrome browser

It says

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at fb (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at Array.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2
at f (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at fb.select (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at Function.fb [as find] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=4.5:2)
at exportTableToCSV (user:746)
at allPayPeriodSummary-controller.js?v=4.5:331
```

I am using this code for download file from html table in angularjs

```
$scope.exportPayPeriods = function(){
     $scope.enableCsv = true;
     setTimeout(function(){
         exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#payPeriod-list-for-csv>table'), 'payPeriod.csv']);
         $scope.enableCsv = false;
     }, 200);
};
```

JS function

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
 var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),

    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
    tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
    colDelim = '","', rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row), $cols = $row.find('td,th');

        return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
            var $col = $(col), text = $col.text();

            return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim).split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim).split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

    // Data URI
    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this).attr({
        'download' : filename,
        'href' : csvData,
        'target' : '_blank'
    });
};
```

I found one similar one [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

In my case its difficult to find that location that where it is creating issue.

Someone please help to find the issue

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Comment: Why did you delete your [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071507/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-to-download-file) from 5 hours ago?

Comment: Updated question