# Getting error while switching to another Frame

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Error:Failed: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.146)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'RADA-HYD-01', ip: '192.168.0.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64',
os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Hi can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Script:

```
browser.switchTo().frame('courses-iframe');
    element(by.css("a[href*='Login']")).getText().then(function (Result) {
      console.log(Result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('courses-iframe'))).then(function(){
        element(by.css("a[href*='Login']")).getText().then(function (Result) {
          console.log(Result);
        });
});
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_TargetLocator.html

the switchto frame expcts number,element and null , not string. Where number is iindex like first frame, second frame etc

Comment: this is the correct answer. the ID is a numeric index of the iframe on the page starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested the following fix:

```
browser.switchTo().frame('courses-iframe');
element(by.css("a[href*='Login']")).getText().then(function (Result) {
  console.log(Result);
});
```

I inserted it into my code and got the following error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Basically what this means is that somewhere in my code, I'm calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until I hit the call stack limit.

[(Taken from the following answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095695/14872460)

I solved my problem by adding

```
      capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      'goog:chromeOptions': {
        w3c: false
       },
       
},
```

Apparently, there's a compatibility issue with the action class and switch on Chrome after version 75.

Hope this helps somehow.