# Angular 11 Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

So I just got this problem, first I solved an issue when I forgot to import certain modules.

Error is "Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded" as title also says. I've tried importing the project into StackBlitz but no luck.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './before-login/welcome/welcome.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './before-login/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './before-login/contact/contact.component';
import { NavComponent } from './before-login/nav/nav.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './before-login/signin/signin.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { InputTextareaModule } from 'primeng/inputtextarea';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { NgAuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/password';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './before-login/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { EmailVerificationComponent } from './before-login/email-verification/email-verification.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './after-login/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './before-login/signup/signup.component';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './after-login/user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { RippleModule } from 'primeng/ripple';
import { FaerdighederComponent } from './after-login/faerdigheder/faerdigheder.component';
import { EnkeltComponent } from './after-login/faerdigheder/enkelt/enkelt.component';
import { KategoriComponent } from './after-login/faerdigheder/kategori/kategori.component';
import { OpgraderComponent } from './after-login/faerdigheder/opgrader/opgrader.component';
import { SlutsideComponent } from './after-login/faerdigheder/slutside/slutside.component';
import { BeskederComponent } from './after-login/beskeder/beskeder.component';
import { UploadService } from './storage/upload.service';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    NavComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    EmailVerificationComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    FaerdighederComponent,
    EnkeltComponent,
    KategoriComponent,
    OpgraderComponent,
    SlutsideComponent,
    BeskederComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    InputTextModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    PasswordModule,
    ToastModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule,
    MessageModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RippleModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule
  ],
  providers: [NgAuthService, UploadService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

user-profile.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadService } from '../../storage/upload.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) { }

  image = this.uploadService.url;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './before-login/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './before-login/contact/contact.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './before-login/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './before-login/signup/signup.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './before-login/welcome/welcome.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './before-login/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { EmailVerificationComponent } from './before-login/email-verification/email-verification.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './after-login/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './after-login/user-profile/user-profile.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: WelcomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signin',
    component: SigninComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-password',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'email-verification',
    component: EmailVerificationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user-profile',
    component: UserProfileComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

upload.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { User } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UploadService {
  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage, private user: User) { }
  iUser = this.user.uid;
  private basePath = `/uploads/images/${this.iUser}`;
  file: File;
  url = '';

  //method to upload file at firebase storage
  async uploadFile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    if (this.file) {
      const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${this.file.name}`;    //path at which image will be stored in the firebase storage
      const snap = await this.afStorage.upload(filePath, this.file);    //upload task
      this.getUrl(snap);
    } else {alert('Please select an image'); }
  }

  //method to retrieve download url
  private async getUrl(snap: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) {
    const url = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    this.url = url;  //store the URL
    console.log(this.url);
  }
}
```

I have no idea, as to where the problem could be. I've looked and changed a few things but changed back to original as the stuff I thought was the problem didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Comment: @Giannis No. I read through but still no idea. I just removed something and commented something out. Still nothing. I commented `image = this.uploadService.url;` out. To see if that was the problem, but no.

Comment: You might have a circular module dependency somewhere in your code, A imports B, imports A.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen I am importing `UploadService` in two places. app.module.ts and user-profile.component.ts

Comment: I also needed to import into app.module.ts because I need to specify it as a provider. Otherwise I would get Error: Error: Internal error: unknown identifier [] as an error.

Comment: Now my ultimate goal was to use the value of `this.url = url` in my user-profile.component.ts as I needed to display the image that I have inside my Firebase Storage. Which can be seen in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have found my issue. I decided to update to Angular 12 and the Ivy Compiler told me I had to use a `@Inject` on my constructor on my upload.service.ts file.