# How do I re-make my program so it uses recursion instead of while-loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop

I made a JavaScript program that randomly finds a certain number out of 100000 and prints out the amount of attempts it took (using a while loop).

Now I'm learning recursive function, and I wonder if it's possible to re-make this program using recursive.
I've tried quite a few times, but with no luck.

Code:

```
let fun30 = num => {
    let attempts = 0;
    let randomNumber = 0;
    while (randomNumber !== num) {
        randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
        attempts++;
    }
    if (randomNumber === num) {
        console.log("It took " + attempts + " attempts");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using recursion is pointless here. If you want to write a recursion function, write one that calculates a number's factorial.

Comment: Consider testing your recursion skill writing a binary search to find a number within the range 0-999. Go to half way, check if the number is higher or lower, then go one quarter way up/down, check if higher lower, then one eighth, etc. Count the steps.

Comment: Recursions and for loop are interchangeable. Since solutions here utilize a tail recursion approach it is quite the same performance as the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let fun30 = num => {
    let attempts = 0;
    let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);;

    if (randomNumber === num) {
        console.log("It took " + attempts + " attempts");
        return attempts + 1;
    }
    else {
       return 1 + fun30(num);
    }
}
```

Yes, recursion is not recommended for this code and problem as there is no assurance when the base condition will be met.

Answer (score 1):

```
let fun30 = num => {
  if (Math.round(Math.random() * 100000) === num) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
      return 1 + fun30(num)
  }
}
```

But this is not recommended as you will probably exceed the [maximum call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)