# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth) when trying to find ratio using Math.max and large array

Tags: javascript

I have a large numerical array (results of an audio file's signal which I return to my react native app from a python backend.

And the array looks like this

```
[1098, 522, 597, 325, 201, 16, ...................... 75, 447, 253, 58, 273]
```

size of the array is around `535754`

I have this code which I use to find raio

```
peaks = audio_signal_array
const ratio = Math.max(...peaks) / 100
// ratio = 1.1 (example result)
const normalized = peaks.map(point => Math.round(point / ratio))
// normalized = [0, 0, 2, 5, 18, 50, 100, 18] (example result)
```

Everytime I run this code it throws me the error

> error [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack
> depth)]

So it would be great if anyone can help me to either fix this code from the javascript side or help me convert this code to python so I can return the ratio and the normalized array to the react native app

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags for your question. If the problem is that a javascript program receives some data and does something wrong (such as throwing an error), even though the data is correct, then that is a javascript question - it **does not matter** what language was used to **create** the data. Python experts will have no particular advantage in answering a question like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
peaks.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
```

instead of

```
Math.max(...peaks)
```

On the python side, you can simply do

```
ratio = max(peaks) / 100
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max:

> ...spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters.