# Why is this recursion program running out of memory?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following recursive program that is called with return type of void.  What's being held in memory to cause stack overflow error?

```js
main();

function main() {
  neverEnd();
}

function neverEnd() {
  console.log("never end");
  neverEnd();
}
```

Comment: You should be getting "Maximum call stack exceeded".

Comment: The stack is causing the stack overflow error. JavaScript (sadly) does not have proper tail recursion, so each recursive call creates a new stack frame.

Comment: You could also be filling up memory with the console log.

Comment: [Javascript Fundamentals — Call Stack and Memory Heap](https://medium.com/@allansendagi/javascript-fundamentals-call-stack-and-memory-heap-401eb8713204)

Comment: The stack…………..

Comment: *"with return type of void"* There is no such thing in JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is creating an infinite loop by recursively calling the neverEnd() function without any exit condition. Each time the function is called, a new stack frame is created to store the function call and its local variables. However, since the function never returns, the stack frames keep piling up on the stack until the system runs out of stack memory and throws a stack overflow error.

In summary, the infinite recursion is causing the program to hold an ever-increasing number of stack frames in memory, which leads to the stack overflow error.

Comment: Is this generated using ChatGPT?