# wordpress "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" from ajax form results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I do not understand javascript very well, so please bear with me if this is obvious.

This question is in regards to using ajax with native wordpress functions to return the results from a forms input.

question: how do i get this to work? id like to submit the form that ive got and have the results displayed on the page using the wordpress ajax functions.

what ive done: ive been following this tutorial/example: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/ (2011 is along time ago, maybe there is a better example i should be following?)

here is the PHP functions that enqueue the scripts (the javascript for the ajax and jquery) along with the function to be called for the ajax results:

```
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "snek_results", get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/results.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'snek_results', 'snek_results', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), false, false);
   wp_enqueue_script( 'snek_results');

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
add_action("wp_ajax_snek_roll", "snek_roll");

wp_localize_script( 'snek_results', 'snek_results', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ))); 

function snek_roll() {

    $choice = $_REQUEST['choice'];
    $bet    = $_REQUEST['bet'];

    ### ERROR CHECKING ###

    if (empty($choice)) {
        $status = array(
                    "status"    => "error",
                    "results"   => "no selection made.",
                );
                echo json_encode($status);
                exit;
    }

    if (empty($bet)) {
        $status = array(
                    "status"    => "error",
                    "results"   => "no bet made.",
                );
                echo json_encode($status);
                exit;
    }

    ### ACTION ###

    if (!empty($choice) && !empty($bet)) {
      
      function roll_dice() {
        $roll_min = 1000;
        $roll_max = 100000;
        $roll = random_int($roll_min, $roll_max);

        return ($roll % 4);
      }

        for ($x = 0; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
        
            $results = roll_dice();

            if ($results == 0) {
              roll_dice();
            }

            if ($results != 0) {
                
                if ($choice == $results) {
                    $status = array(
                        "status"    => "winner",
                        "choice"    => $choice,
                        "results"   => $results,
                        "bet"       => $bet,
                        "prize"     => $bet * 2.5
                    );
                    echo json_encode($status);
                    exit;
                
                }
                
                else {
                    $status = array(
                        "status"    => "loser",
                        "choice"    => $choice,
                        "results"   => $results,
                        "bet"       => $bet,
                        "prize" => 0
                    );

                    echo json_encode($status);
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the javascript for the results:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("form").submit(function (event) {
      var formData = {
          choice: $("input[name='choice']:checked").val(),
          bet: $("input[name='bet']:checked").val()
      };
 
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url : snek_results.ajaxurl,
          data : {action: "snek_results", bet : bet, choice: choice},
          dataType: "json",
          encode: true,
      }).done(function (data) {
          if (data["status"] == "winner") {
          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Status: " + data["status"];
          }
          if (data["status"] == "loser") {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Status: " + data["status"];
          }
      });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

my problem is:

1. i dont really understand javascript and ajax very well.
2. when i submit the form, i get the error: jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size -- that error goes by super quick and then the page reloads.

what i would like:

1. id like to know what that error is about and why its happening.
2. advice on where ive gone wrong on this implementation of ajax in wordpress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095695/7698734

This answers your question

Comment: problem seems to be related to the recursive call to the `roll_dice()`