# Error deploying Next.js app on Vercel: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have encountered the following error while deploying my **Next.js** application on **Vercel**:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:18889)
    at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:18918)
    at parse.fastpaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:18997)
    at picomatch.makeRe (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:21635)
    at picomatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19637)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19294
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at picomatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19286)
    at micromatch.isMatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:1090)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I couldn't use debugging options, like `NODE_DEBUG=regex npm run build`, to gain new insights.

I appreciate any suggestions and thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using sharp version 0.33.1 resolved the issue for me.

Removing sharp too

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you accidentally call a function, then in that function, you call another function, and so on until it reaches the limit. Common symptoms are:

- You call the function inside itself without a break check.
- You import a module inside itself

People discuss multiple reasons here, maybe it could give you some clues: [Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)